# Magento 2 Rest api created category not displaying backend

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I created Product category using rest Api. It doesn't give any error and it give category id and others its sign to it created successfully but I checked in backend
it does't appear .I try to re indexing but same result.
here is my code  to used create category

```
<?php

// Authentication rest API magento2, get access token

$ch = curl_init();
$data = array(
    "username" => $username,
    "password" => $password
);
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init($token_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)
));
$token = curl_exec($ch);
$adminToken = json_decode($token);

// ////////////**************************************************//////////////

$newCategoryJson = '{
    "category": {
        "name": "test",
        "level": 1,
        "path": "1",
        "isActive": true
    },
    "saveOptions": true
}';
$setHaders = array(
    'Content-Type:application/json',
    'Authorization:Bearer ' . $adminToken
);
$ch = curl_init("http://demo.magento.com/magento2/project-community-edition/index.php/rest/V1/categories");

// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $setHaders);

$curlOptions = array(
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $newCategoryJson,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $setHaders
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOptions);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo var_dump($response);
```

Here is MY response json response

```
{
    "id": 42,
    "parent_id": 1,
    "name": "test",
    "is_active": true,
    "position": 2,
    "level": 1,
    "children": "2,3,9,11,20,37,38",
    "created_at": "2016-09-23 02:51:47",
    "updated_at": "2016-09-23 02:51:47",
    "path": "1",
    "available_sort_by": [],
    "include_in_menu": true,
    "custom_attributes": [{
        "attribute_code": "is_anchor",
        "value": "1"
    }, {
        "attribute_code": "path",
        "value": "1"
    }, {
        "attribute_code": "children",
        "value": "2,3,9,11,20,37,38"
    }, {
        "attribute_code": "children_count",
        "value": "0"
    }, {
        "attribute_code": "url_key",
        "value": "test"
    }]
}
```

Nackend
[image]

**Edit**
I checked Database also It On Database also.

Comment: Please check 1st in Database, Then try to Clear Cache as well

Comment: I clear cache also re index but not  success. but not checked database I will check  it.but why it not displaying

Comment: Yes Its on database also.but not show in backend

Answer (score 1):

Follow below checklist

- Make sure it will be in database
- It has parent as "Default Category"
- Make sure your new Category is "Enable"
- Clear Cache & Check in Another Browser as well.

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes it is on database,also has parent as default category,its enable and i try to clear cache and re indexing but no luck

Comment: @ankit Shah: I am using "rest/V1/categories/" (Magento 2 Rest API). In documentation(http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/) it says "Retrieve list of categories" but it only returns default category(and its all children) every time. How can i get the list of all categories(those which are parent).

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should not specify "path" and "level" in post data. Below data works for me.

```
{
    "category": {
        "name": "test2",
        "parent_id":1,
        "isActive": true
    },
    "saveOptions": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old post, but if anyone need help in this situation, the true parent_id (for default category) is 2 not 1, and there is no need to specify path, so the json should look like this:

```
{
    "category": {
    "name": "test",
    "level": 1,
    "parent_id": 2,
    "isActive": true
},
    "saveOptions": true
}
```